# Spring Security: Referer always login page after authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have sprint security setup like this:

```
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/MyAccount").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/additem").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
        .and().csrf().disable();
```

When I start on page Foo and click to /additem (not logged in) it redirects me (302) to /login.  When I submit the login form REFERER is set to the login page not FOO or /additem.  Thus I'm brought back to the login page albeit logged in.  What am I missing?

Here is the code for the auth Handler:

```
public AuthSuccessHandler() {
    super();
    log.info("empty constructor called");
    setDefaultTargetUrl("/popular-links");
    setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(false);
    //setUseReferer(true); <-- causes issues
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026801/spring-security-referer-always-login-page-after-authentication
  }

  @Override
   public void onAuthenticationSuccess( HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication ){
          String email = authentication.getName();
          UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)authentication.getPrincipal();
          log.info("Successful auth : "+email);
          String token = tokenProvider.createToken(email, userDetails.getAuthorities());
          log.info("Token: "+token);
          sessionInfo.setJwtToken(token);
          try {
            handle(request,response,authentication);
          } catch (Exception e){
            log.error("An error occured "+e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
   }
```

Comment: Well, you have custom success handler, which could be causing the issue. Do you mind posting the code for it?

Comment: I added that code to the original post.  That said, the issue I see is occurring before then.  The post to do the login already has the REFERER set to /login and not the previous page, so I'm not sure how the auth handler would even know where to refer to.